# Responsive bootstrap designing in CakePHP 3x

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

As CakePHP 3x has inbuilt responsive feature, I would like to know the element structures and class definitions. 
 I'm indeed familiar with Twitter Bootstrapping ( done in cake 2x projects). But need to familiarize with CakePHP 3x version, as its new in framework! 
 I looked into **css/base.css** and found few classes for elements, like

```
Grids: .small-1(to 12), .medium-1(to 12), .large-1(to 12)
Offsets:  .small-offset-1(to 12), .medium-offset-1(to 12), .large-offset-1(to 12) 
Align: .left, .right.... etc
```

As responsive sites run with standard element structures, is there any reference for the Cake's bootstrapping, like forms,blocks etc?

Comment: Cake 3.x now uses [**Foundation**](http://foundation.zurb.com/) as a default, however you are by no means forced to use it, you can ofcourse exchange it for Bootstrap or any other framework.

Comment: I don't know what the question is here.

Comment: I didn't get your question. But if the question is about functionality of 3.0 having same as 2.0 then "Yes". You should be more clear with your coding standards in 3.0. You can use any bootstrap or foundation in cakephp 3.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CakePHP 3 uses the [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) front-end framework 'out-of-the-box'. Which means that the classes you want to use will be listed in their documentation.

[Specifically the page about the grids](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html).

You can customise, remove or replace [the provided default css](https://github.com/cakephp/app/tree/master/webroot/css) if you want to. It is only provided so that you can 'hit the ground running' and so that new users are presented with a more organised front-end look when they first start using the framework.

If you'd like to review the history of this change, you can [check the PR on Github](https://github.com/cakephp/app/pull/150).