# CakePHP 3 responsive design, there is any notation?

Tags: html, css, cakephp, responsive-design, cakephp-3.0

I'm starting with CakePHP 3 and I see new CSS and responsive design support; I've searched info about styles utilization because I want to put custom backgrounds depending device width (using min-width of mq-small, mq-medium, mq-large, mq-xlarge, mq-xxlarge. from cake css) but I didn't found info.

There is documentation about this? Is a plug-in or is a css only for responsive columns?. This code can be seen in css "base.css" from cakephp 3 (I'm using 3.0.2)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP 3 uses the Zurb Foundation front-end framework. Which means that the classes you want to use will be listed in their [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

For responsive design you will want to look into the [grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/grid.html).

Good luck!

Comment: copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688614/responsive-bootstrap-designing-in-cakephp-3x