# What version of Foundation is used in cakePHP3?

Tags: css, cakephp, zurb-foundation, cakephp-3.0

From an earlier question ([Responsive bootstrap designing in CakePHP 3x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688614/responsive-bootstrap-designing-in-cakephp-3x)) I understand that cakePHP3 are using Foundation for front-end framework, but which version (in cakePHP v.3.2)? 
I'm struggling with a toggled top-bar, that won't open when minimized. There seems to have been some bugs in the 5th version and I'm now wondering if they aren't fixed in the version that cakePHP3 are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CakPHP application templates `base.css` file was last updated with foundation on September the 1st of 2015

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/commit/3bf179e04d48c859b4ba411d81607ae25d275b3b**

As far as I can tell, this is version 5.5.2. If you need a newer version, then simply don't use the templates default CSS, there is absolutely no need to stick with what ships with the template.

Also you can file an issue on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/app) and suggest an update, or even create pull request and update it yourself.

Comment: re:'absolutely no need to stick with what ships with'
-- afaik the Html/Form helpers produce markup tailored to this particular css framework which introduces (sort of) a need to stick with that :)

Comment: @ptica I was referring to updating the framework, which was the OPs concern. Only a few helper methods produce markup that is "tied" to foundation out of the box (don't nail me down on it, but IIRC only the paginator helper does), and updating the foundation framework doesn't necessarily have to cause problems with them, especially not if its a minor version update. In any case the markup produced by the helpers can easily be customized in the blink of an eye, so there's not even the need to stick with foundation at all.