# CakePhp 3 Form element gets hidden when validation fails

Tags: css, cakephp, zurb-foundation-6

I try to build a form in Cakephp 3 with a validator. Problem is the resulting css, as it hides the input element!

It shows the error message alright, below the hidden input element.

The Form with schema and validator:

```
namespace App\Form;

use Cake\Form\Form;
use Cake\Form\Schema;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class ContactForm extends Form
{
  protected function _buildSchema(Schema $schema)
  {
    return $schema
      ->addField('name', 'string')
      ->addField('email', ['type' => 'email'])
      ->addField('message', 'string');
  }

  protected function _buildValidator(Validator $validator)
  {
    return $validator
      ->add('name', 'length', [
        'rule' => ['minLength', 1],
        'message' => _('Please fill in your name')
      ])
      ->add('email', 'format', [
        'rule' => 'email',
        'message' => __('This must be a valid email address')
      ])
      ->add('message', 'length', [
        'rule' => ['minLength', 15],
        'message' => __('The message must be at least 15 characters')
      ]);
  }

  protected function _execute(array $data)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

The .ctp file's form code:

```
echo $this->Form->create($form);

echo $this->Form->input('name', ['title' => __('Name')]);
echo $this->Form->input('email', ['title' => __('Email')]);
echo $this->Form->input('message', ['title' => __('Message')]);//, 'type' => 'textarea']);

echo $this->Form->submit(__('Submit'), ['class' => 'button top-margin']);
echo $this->Form->end();
```

The code in the controller:

```
$form = new ContactForm();

if($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) 
{

      if($form->execute($this->request->getData())) 
      {
        // Values seem correct. Push away an email to support!
        $data = $this->request->data;    
      } 
      else 
      {
        $this->Flash->error(__('There was a problem submitting your form. Please check the error message below each input field.'));
      }
    }

    $this->set('form', $form);
```

If I show the form, add some name and email, but leave the message input field with one letter, the validation fails as expected with the error message "The message must be at least 15 characters".

But the css-class "form-error" is set to the input field, which is hiding the input field entirely!

#### Resulting html:

```
<div class="input text required error"><label for="message">Message</label>
  <input type="text" name="message" title="Message" required="required" id="message" class="form-error" value="a">
  <div class="error-message">The message must be at least 15 characters</div>
</div>
```

Css for 'form-error':

```
.form-error {
    display: none;
    margin-top: -0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #cc4b37;
}
```

Using CakePHP version: 3.5.17 and Zurb foundation 6.5.3.

What's wrong here? I assumed Zurb and Cake are 'married', so cake produce html compatible with zurb. At least it has been like that, but maybe they have changed?

Comment: I found an older post about the relation between zurb and cake here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745049/what-version-of-foundation-is-used-in-cakephp3    ....problem still present though, html produced by cake is not 'compatible' with zurb 6.5.

Comment: I got it after some research: the html/css generated by cake seems to be simply outdated. I decided to use zurbs abide, form validation client side. Means double validation though, the web developers eternal pain. (client-side, then server-side validation)

Comment: remove the `display: none;` In your css style `.form-error` class