# Using Foundation Zurb with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, zurb-foundation

Why does foundation zurb is not working well with my CakePHP project?
as far as I know from version 3 it's built in.

This code:

```
<span class="secondary badge">2</span>
<span class="success badge">3</span>
<span class="alert badge">A</span>
<span class="warning badge">B</span>
```

Should print:
[image]

While my output is:
[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell from looking through CakePHP 3 it's not included. You will have to add it to the layout you are using.

Comment: that's the topic that I'm relying on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688614/responsive-bootstrap-designing-in-cakephp-3x

Comment: I've looked through the default CSS (base.css) that comes with the initial install. It does not include badges. If you try something like `<button type="button" class="success button">Save</button>` it does use Foundation as long as you have included base.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [app skeleton](https://github.com/cakephp/app) uses only a subset of Zurb Foundation. So instead of the default css files you need to download and use Foundation's full (custom version which includes the elements you want) css.

Comment: The css files in foundation are scss (app.scss, _settings.scss) located in the assets folder. All I need is to copy them to my project and import them?

Comment: You need to include the .css files in your layout, browsers can't directly use .scss.